# Why does json_encode returns object instead of string?

Tags: javascript, php

PHP json_encode

> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of the supplied value. [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

but it returns JavaScript object not a Json string:

```
  <script>
   var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
   alert(app.name)
 </script>
```

Comment: It returns a string **in PHP**, which is then echoed and becomes part of the HTML page in which it is executable JavaScript. So for PHP it is a string, but the way it is passed to the client, it is parsed by the browser as JavaScript.

Comment: JSON literally stands for **JavaScript Object Notation**. So as @trincot, mentioned PHP treats it as a string, but once your browser interprets it in javascript, it will get treated as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation).

Answer (score 0):

> but it returns JavaScript object not a Json string

You skip a few steps here:

1. `json_encode` returns a string in PHP
2. That string is given to the `echo` statement
3. Everything that is output, is passed as the HTML page for the browser to interpret
4. The browser uses its JavaScript engine to **parse** the scripts that are part of the page -- that JSON is parsed as any other object literal that might occur in the script.
5. To the JavaScript engine, this part of the script is *not* a string, but an object literal.

It may help to rewrite the PHP script to something that is equivalent:

```php
echo "
  <script>
   var app = " . json_encode($array) . ";
   alert(app.name)
 </script>";
```

So now it is clear that PHP sends *one* string, which happens to represent valid JavaScript -- enclosed in a `<script>` tag. The JSON is just a part of that long string, which later the browser will parse, and where the JavaScript part is parsed by a JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 0):

> but it returns JavaScript object not a Json string:

Context matters, consider this code:

```
<?php
$array = ['name' => 'John Doe'];
$string = json_encode($array);
var_dump($string);
```

Executing that produces:

```
$ php index.php
string(19) "{"name":"John Doe"}"
```

`string(19)` means the variable is a string of 19 characters. The fact that string can be interpretted by js as an object is immaterial here, to php it is producing a string.